# Check for duplicate usernames prevents updating user

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I have the below Java controller for adding a user:

```
@GetMapping("/registration")
public String registration(Model model) {
    if (securityService.isAuthenticated()) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    model.addAttribute("userForm", new User());

    return "registration";
}
```

I also have the following validator to prevent duplicate usernames:

```
if (userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {
    errors.rejectValue("username", "Duplicate.userForm.username");
}
```

I'm now trying to add a controller to updating an existing user. I created the below to use the same registration form as when creating a user:

```
@GetMapping("/users/showFormForUpdate")
public String showFormForUpdate(@RequestParam("userId") long theId, Model theModel) {
        
    User theUser = userService.findById(theId);
        
    theModel.addAttribute("userForm", theUser);
        
    return "registration";
}
```

My problem is that when I attempt to update my duplicate user alert appears if I do not change the username.

This is my code in the registration form that gives the alert:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"
                       autofocus="true">
    <span style="color:red" class="has-error" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('username')}" th:errors="*{username}"></span>
</div>
```

In summary, when I create a user I want any duplicate usernames to be flagged but if I'm updating the user I don't want this. How can I update my user but maintain the ability to prevent duplicate users? I'm using `addAttribute` in `org.springframework.ui.Model`. I know one option would be to use a different form for the update but I would expect there should be a way to do both with one form.

Comment: Please be specific what the exact problem is. `My problem is that when I attempt to update my duplicate user alert.`

Comment: Apologies. Long day! I updated my question. Hope that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> if (userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null) {
>   errors.rejectValue("username", "Duplicate.userForm.username"); }
> ```

Avoid the above code level validation and let the database complain if the username is a duplicate. i.e. during registration since the `User` object does not have a `userId`, JPA does an `insert`, and if duplicates present, you will get notified by a `DataIntegrityViolationException`. During update, JPA does an `update` since the `userId` is present, and does not result in a `DataIntegrityViolationException`.